# How to output the number of channels in a .JP2

Tags: raster, imagery, jpeg-2000

I am looking for any tool (or python code snippet) that can loop through a file folder of .jp2 images and determine which have 3 bands and which have 4 bands.

I am having trouble creating a raster dataset as some of them have 3 bands and others have 4. I need to isolate the band count and replace the images with only 3 bands. I am looking to output a text file that has the name of the file which has 3 bands.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GDAL can help you do this. You can use GDAL's python API

```
import os
from osgeo import gdal

for f in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
  ds = gdal.Open(f)
  if ds.RasterCount == 3:
    print f
```

Comment: I will try tomorrow and see how it goes! thanks for the quick comment.

Comment: Can you tell me where I would place the script? does it go in the directory? e.g.P:\Data\Aerials\2010\Orthos\zip where all the files are located? or does it go in the code snippet somewhere?

Comment: It would go in the data directory. If you want to run it from elsewhere, replace os.getCwd() with the full path to the directory containing the rasters.